# Using bitwise AND operation in haskell

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation, bit

why doesn't the code

```
import Data.Bits

a = (.&.) 6 9
```

give me

```
9
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work. Cheers !

Comment: Why would you expect it to be 9?

Comment: On a side note, I came here to check that `.&.` is indeed how Haskell defines the bitwise and operator.

Answer (score 36):

Because 6 `AND` 9 = 0

```
0110   = 6
&
1001   = 9
-----
0000   = 0
```